# Loop through IQueryable sub object and find properties with value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have a IQueryable query
The Instructor object has (using entity framework) a related object:  `IEnumerable<Course> Courses` 
Each course has a title property: `string CourseTitle`.

I'm trying to filter all those courses whose title contains the string abc.

I have tried following approach which I'm quite uncertain of:

```
query = from i in query.SelectMany(p => p.Courses)
        .Where(j => j.CourseTitle.Contains(courseTitle))
```

I would prefer doing it using a Lambda expression.

Comment: entity framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should probably look like this given that courseTitle = "abc" due to match your question and example.

```
var result = from x in query
             from course in x.Courses
             where course.CourseTitle.Contains(courseTitle)
             select x;
```

or...

```
var result = query.SelectMany(x => x.Courses, (x, course) => new {x, course})
                  .Where(obj => obj.course.CourseTitle.Contains(courseTitle))
                  .Select(obj => obj.x);
```

Comment: Thanks the first solved it, the second cannot be used since it return a list of course objects

Comment: @Ovis  You're correct and apologies... I've updated the lamba version that I believe correctly performs the query like the first. All this was done from the top of my head without designer so I'm blundering.